# MathJax fraction with two-digit denominator

Tags: mathjax

```
\frac{1}{10}
```

render as 1/1 0

[image]

How can I display 1/10?

Comment: It renders as 1/10 for me. How is your MathJax set up?

Answer (score 1):

It was due to a race condition. I was calling `MathJax.typeset();` before the string was received from the API and fully rendered in the dom.

I am using MathJax in the context of a React application, to interpret a string that comes from an API.

Here's what I do now, based on Gist by GiacoCorsiglia: [Using MathJax v3 in React](https://gist.github.com/GiacoCorsiglia/1619828473f4b34d3d914a16fcbf10f3).

In `index.html`:

```
<script>
  window.__MathJax_State__ = {
    isReady: false,
    promise: new Promise(resolve => {

      window.MathJax = {
        // MathJax can be configured as desired in addition to these options.
        startup: {
          // Don't perform an initial typeset of the page when MathJax loads.
          // Our React components will trigger typsetting as needed.
          typeset: false,
          ready: () => {
            // Do whatever MathJax would normally do at this point.
            MathJax.startup.defaultReady();
            // Set the flag and resolve the promise.
            window.__MathJax_State__.isReady = true;
            resolve();
          }
        }
      };

    })
  };
</script>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg.js"></script>
```

In my `component.jsx` that renders the string, I'm using `useEffect()`:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    // Avoid running this script if the MathJax library hasn't loaded yet.
    if (!isMathJaxReady) {
      // But trigger a re-render of this component once it is loaded.
      __MathJax_State__.promise.then(() => setIsMathJaxReady(true));
      return;
    }
    
    MathJax.typeset();

  },[stringFromAPI, isMathJaxReady, setIsMathJaxReady]);
```